# Custom Error Message to show current function

Tags: c#-4.0

In my current error handling, I specify the Form, function and error message in a messagebox similar to the following.

```
try
{
  //Some code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Form Title : " + this.Title + "\nFunction : CurrentFunction \nError : " + ex.Message);
     return;
}
```

This works for me, but was curious if I can make the process even more simple, and generate the function name, instead of typing it out every time I want to display the error message.

**Additionally**:
I know you can include the stacktrace and view the top few lines, but I was curious if there was a cleaner way to show the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you just need the current function (not the calling function), you can use [`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod(VS.80).aspx):

```
string currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```